# iAd revenue questions

Tags: iphone

my app got recently approved, 
and I have a few questions regarding iAd.

1) How much exactly is revenue per impression and per click?

2) I have not seen ads showing up on my own device, but they do show up on my friends' devices. Is it supposed to be like this?

3) What if someone clicks on different ads multiple times on the same device, say, throughout the day? Is it still the same amount of revenue per click? or does it count as once since it is on the same device? If it is allowed, wouldn't that be a source of sort of an intentional multi-clicking just for sake of revenues?

4) How frequently are the revenues deposited to your account?

5) Does click-through rate increase just by clicking the ad, or actually installing it?

that's about it.
Please clarify these issues for me!
Thank you.

Comment: There's no possible answer for #1. It'll vary. This is off-topic, anyways.

Comment: it's always these ppl to close useful questions.